# are the Zero and Zero W software compatible?

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w, compatibility, software-compatibility

I'm having problems on a brand new Zero, I prepared the SD on a Zero W to install updates and other via internet, I disabled bluetooth and I left wifi enebled in case I'll need to change something on the SD using the Zero W headless.

on the Zero W all works like a charm but when I move the SD on the Zero it freezes.

so:

1 ) are the Zero and Zero W software compatible?

2 ) or do I need to disable both blueetooth and wifi to make it work on the Zero?

3 ) or maybe my Zero is faulty?

4 ) otherwhise how can I set up a Zero without internet connection, download updates from another computer and then move them to the Zero using an USB stick would be annoying

**UPDATE**

I formatted the SD card using SD Card Formatter then I wrote on it the **2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-lite** image, I changed **config.txt** and **cmdline.txt** as described [here](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/) for gadget mode, when I booted the 1st time it got stuck on:

[image]

after 5min it rebooted and then got stucked on:

[image]

after 2min it rebooted and then got stucked on:

[image]

touching it I almost burned myself for how hot it was, definitely faulty?

Comment: 1) yes, except for wifi/bt 2) yes 3) don't know 4) use gadget mode

Comment: so do you think the cause of freezes could be the wifi enabled?

Comment: not sure to be honest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OS loads correctly but randomly freezes, there might be something wrong with the RPi, but if the boot process gets interrupted, or paused for a very long time without letting you login it most likely means the DHCP server is trying to find the interface in which your Pi was set and thus you may need to boot again on the other Pi and disable wifi, or create a new image using this  Pi Zero.

Comment: I have the boot option wait for network disabled, so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I added to **/boot/config.txt** `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` and `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi` but still freezes, a faulty Pi?

Comment: If you added the wifi settings on your pi manually, it might want to do the network first... try leaving it until it asks you to login or until it actually fully boots. wait up to maybe 20 minutes... if nothing then I would say try a different image.

Comment: If you don't have a second sd card you can backup this one unto a .iso in mac or .img in linux and reformat it and start over knowing you haven't lost your work on the previous image. See here for instructions: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17789160-backing-up-and-restoring-your-raspberry-pis-sd-card

Comment: currently I can login, it freezes when I run my python script that captures images to a USB stick, which on the Zero W works. also I tried on the Zero another SD (always prepared on the Zero W) and it freezes when running scripts or browsing directories. so probably a faulty Pi?

Comment: So if you prepare all SD cards on the Pi W and; use them on the non W, I would prepare one from the Zero, if you are doing it because you can’t download updates or connect to internet, try connecting the Pi Zero to a computer through serial for internet sharing

Comment: So they are not 100% compatible?

Comment: also I noticed an average working temperature of the Zero about 15 degrees higher compared to the Zero W with same SD

Comment: I tried to prepare the SD card on the non W, see update

Comment: yeah, maybe a short of some sort, since you said it's super hot... I mean these things aren't that expensive, at this point I'd suggest replacing it now.

Comment: so next time can I still prepare the SD on the Zero W with no "Wait for Network" preference or do you recommend to use gadget mode on the Zero?

Comment: I have a few of these I'll do some tests, but from experience, I would assume you can, the OS will automatically detect if something's missing.

Comment: if you do tests, let me know

Comment: @Miky, I have tested it, if you create an image and modify it using a ZeroW  you can still use it in both. so your RPi was definitely defective. I used the image on both Pis and were working well.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to disable bluetooth and wifi to use it on the Zero?

Comment: You do not, it might take a bit longer to boot because whether or not you add static IP, it might be looking for the network card